# how to compile a C# code target .NET 5 at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net-5

I tried the example in this link: (Target .NET 5)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters?view=net-5.0

but it throws `PlatformNotSupportedException` exception in this line:

```
// Invoke compilation.
CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, sourceFile);
```

Any suggestion to make it works?

Comment: Is everything in your source file .Net 5 compatible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655478/cannot-compile-simple-dynamic-code-after-migration-on-netstandard-2-0-codedom

Comment: Yes, The project target .Net 5, and it's .Net 5 compatible, everything else works correctly

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked Hans Passant.